# Can destructuring an array be used to map properties of each elements?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Suppose there is an array like this:

```
const a = [ {p:1}, {p:2}, {p:3} ];
```

Is it possible to destructure this array in order to obtain `p = [1, 2, 3]` ?

Because this does not work :

```
const [ ...{ p } ] = a;   // no error, same as const p = a.p;
// p = undefined;
```

---

**Edit**

In response to all the answers saying that I need to use `Array.prototype.map`, I am aware of this. I was simply wondering if there was a way to map *during* the destructuring process, and the answer is : no, I need to destructure the array itself, then use map as a separate step.

For example:

```
const data = {
   id: 123,
   name: 'John',
   attributes: [{ id:300, label:'attrA' }, { id:301, label:'attrB' }]
};

function format(data) {
  const { id, name, attributes } = data;
  const attr = attributes.map(({ label }) => label);
  return { id, name, attr };
}

console.log( format(data) };
// { id:123, name:'John', attr:['attrA', 'attrB'] }
```

I was simply wondering if there was a way, directly during destructuring, without using `map` (and, respectfully, without the bloated `lodash` library), to retrive all `label` properties into an array of strings.

Comment: No, it can't, and it shouldn't.

Comment: The general way to do this is by using `.map()` (as shown below) and in these answers: [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865)

Comment: the best you can do is `const p = a.map(({p})=>p)`

Comment: Yes, I am aware of using `Array.prototype.map`, I'm asking because if the array is                                                                         a deep property, I wanted to do that inline, but it seems like I have to destructure the array value, then map as a separate step.

Comment: You probably want to use a library like Xpath/JSONPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I think that what you are looking for doesn't exist, normally you would `map` the array to create a new array using values from properties. In this specific case it would be like this

```
const p = a.map(element => element.p)
```

Of course, there are some packages that have many utilities to help, like [Lodash's map function with the 'property' iteratee](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of using Array.prototype.map, I'm asking because if the array is a deep property, I wanted to do that inline, but it seems like I have to destructure the array value, then map as a separate step.

Answer (score 0):

you can destructure the first item like this :

```
const [{ p }] = a;
```

but for getting all values you need to use .map

and the simplest way might be this :

```
const val = a.map(({p}) => p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalized solution that groups all properties into arrays, letting you destructure any property:

```js
const group = (array) => array.reduce((acc,obj) => {
  for(let [key,val] of Object.entries(obj)){
    acc[key] ||= [];
    acc[key].push(val)
    }
    return acc
  }, {})

const ar = [ {p:1}, {p:2}, {p:3} ]; 
const {p} = group(ar)
console.log(p)

const ar2 = [{a:2,b:1},{a:5,b:4}, {c:1}]
const {a,b,c} = group(ar2)
console.log(a,b,c)
```